# Binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand (or there is no acceptable conversation)

Tags: c++, class, oop, operator-keyword

I'm getting an error I've mentioned in the title in particular part of code where I'm oveloading an operator '='. The '=' seems to work on its own when, but when I combine '=' operator with '+' operator things get messy

Main.cpp:

```
#include "MyString.h"
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    char String1[] = "abcdef";
    MyString NewString(String1);

    char String2[] = "cd";
    MyString SubString(String2);

    cout << NewString.GetStringLength() << endl;
    cout << SubString.GetStringLength() << endl;
    NewString = (SubString + SubString); // Here I get an error
    cout << NewString.GetStringLength() << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Class constructors and operators:

```
    MyString::MyString() {
    StringLength = 0;
    Pointer = nullptr;
}

    MyString::MyString(const char* String) {
    for (int i = 0; String[i]; i++)
        StringLength++;
    Pointer = new char[StringLength + 1];
    char *Source = (char *)String;
    char *Destination = (char *)Pointer;
    for (int i = 0; i < StringLength + 1; i++)
        Destination[i] = Source[i];
}

    MyString::MyString(int Length)
        :Pointer(new char[Length + 1]), StringLength(Length) { 
    Pointer[Length] = 0;

   MyString MyString::operator=(MyString &String) {
    int BigLength;
    int SmallLength;
    this->StringLength > String.StringLength ?
        BigLength = this->StringLength, SmallLength =     String.StringLength :
        BigLength = String.StringLength, SmallLength = this-    >StringLength;
    this->StringLength = String.StringLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < SmallLength - 1; i++)
        this->Pointer[i] = String.Pointer[i];
    for (int i = SmallLength; i < BigLength - 1; i++)
        this->Pointer[i] = 0;
    return *this;
};

MyString MyString::operator+(MyString &String) {
    MyString TempString(this->StringLength + String.StringLength);
    for (int i = 0; i < this->StringLength; i++)
    TempString.Pointer[i] = this->Pointer[i];
        for (int i = 0; i < String.StringLength; i++)
        TempString.Pointer[i + this->StringLength] =     String.Pointer[i];
return TempString;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Temporary object returned by

```
(SubString + SubString)
```

cannot be bound to lvalue reference - `MyString::operator=(MyString &String)`.

Copy assignment operator should take its param by *const Lvalue reference*:

```
MyString::operator=(const MyString &String)
```

Comment: Same with `operator+`, too (and the whole operator should be marked as `const` as well)

Answer (score 0):

For starters this constructor

```
    MyString::MyString(const char* String) {
    for (int i = 0; String[i]; i++)
        StringLength++;
    Pointer = new char[StringLength + 1];
    char *Source = (char *)String;
    char *Destination = (char *)Pointer;
    for (int i = 0; i < StringLength + 1; i++)
        Destination[i] = Source[i];
}
```

is invalid provided that with the class definition the data member `StringLength` is not zero initialized.

Also it is a bad idea to cast a pointer to constant data to pointer to non-constant data.

The constructor can look the following way

```
    MyString::MyString(const char* String) : StringLength( 0 ) {
    while ( String[StringLength] ) ++StringLength;

    Pointer = new char[StringLength + 1];

    for ( char *Destination = Pointer; ( *Destination++ = *String++ ) != '\0'; );
}
```

In this constructor

```
MyString::MyString(int Length)
    :Pointer(new char[Length + 1]), StringLength(Length) { 
    Pointer[Length] = 0;
}
```

there should be

```
    Pointer[0] = '\0';
```

instead of

```
    Pointer[Length] = 0;
```

The assignment operator should gave the parameter as a constant reference.

```
MyString MyString::operator =( const MyString &String );
                               ^^^^^
```

Moreover the operator has undefined behavior when the length of String is greater than the length of this->Pointer.

In this case you have to allocate a new character array large enough to accommodate the source string and delete the previous character array.